# Laravel Passport - unable create key file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have a project in Laravel 8.0. This project is living on server. Now I'm trying setup it on my local environment using docker.

I almost done it but I have one issue with laravel/passport.
When I try run any artisan command (even "php artisan passport:keys") always I have following error.

> In CryptKey.php line 69:
> Unable to read key from file
> file:///var/www/html/storage/oauth-private.key

So it's correct because keys are not created yet. But I'm not able generate new one.

It looks like laravel/passport checking this keys with every command even when I try to create it.

How can I skip this checking when command fired. Or how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In class **AuthServiceProvider** in **boot()** method where following instructions:

```
$server = $this->app->make(AuthorizationServer::class);
$server->enableGrantType(new PersonalAccessGrant(), new DateInterval("P{$tokenLifetime}D"));
```

So this method is always fired not only on request but on command call too.

To solve issue we need just add checking before **$this->app->make(** call.

```
if (app()->runningInConsole()) {
   return;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This command should run on server if not create then there is the server some permission issue

Best Example  https://www.laravelcode.com/post/laravel-8-api-authentication-using-passport-from-the-scratch

[This command should run on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfize.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32784859)

Answer (score -2):

I think the key itself is not generated. So use the below command to generate key first.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

And then run,

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

If this din't work, Then It must be the permission issue. Provide enough read permission to `storage` folder. Try the below command in the terminal,

```
sudo chmod 755 -R storage
```

Comment: It's not with APP_KEY problem, its problem with "oauth-private.key". I wrote in my question I'm not able to run any command. And there is no permission issue.

Comment: Editted the answer. Try the above.

Comment: Please read my question one more time. I'm not able to run any command. Not only generate passport key.

Comment: You will not be able to write `php artisan` commands. Try `sudo chmod 755 -R storage`. Should work. If this dint work. Give the same permission to entire laravel project file itself.

Comment: Why I'm not be able write artisan commands?

Comment: Few artisan commands will read the contents inside your project. And the folder does'nt have enough permissions. So there is a possibility that these kind of errors might happen

Comment: I set chmods for all project and nothing changed.

Comment: Try `php artisan passport:install --force`.

Comment: What error are getting when you use `php artisan serve` ?